# Only last execution of $.each seems to be executing

Tags: jquery

Here's the code:

```
// Each ul that holds the collection of our entities
var lists = ['ul.emails', 'ul.phoneNumbers'];

// Setup the "add" link
var $addLink = $('<a href="#" class="margin-left btn btn-mini add"><i class="icon-plus"></i>label</a>');
var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>').append($addLink);

$(document).ready(function() {

  // Add link to each list
  $.each(lists, function(index, list) { 
    $(list).append($newLinkLi);
  });

});
```

But, only the last `ul` gets the link. If, however, I do

```
  $.each(lists, function(index, list) { 
    $(list).append('test');
  });
```

it works. What gives? Is something being passed by reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending an element that already exists in the DOM just moves that element, it does not create a new element.

```
var lists   = ['ul.emails', 'ul.phoneNumbers'],
    addLink = '<a href="#" class="margin-left btn btn-mini add"><i class="icon-plus"></i>label</a>';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each(lists, function(index, list) { 
        var $newLinkLi = $('<li />').append(addLink);
        $(list).append($newLinkLi);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to clone the element first, otherwise it gets moved around the DOM instead.

```
$(list).append($newLinkLi.clone());
```

Answer (score 0):

You're handling only one `element` instead of using element string representation.

```
// Each ul that holds the collection of our entities
var lists = ['ul.emails', 'ul.phoneNumbers'];

// Setup the "add" link
var $addLink = '<li><a href="#" class="margin-left btn btn-mini add"><i class="icon-plus"></i>label</a></li>';


$(document).ready(function() {

  // Add link to each list
  $.each(lists, function(index, list) { 
    $(list).append($addLink );
  });

});
```